# universal ios app iPad and iPhone architecture

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm creating a universal iOS app.
I have a different UI for each one of them in most of the screens.
There are about 15 screens.
I'm coming from Android and trying to find the best solution for that.

1. on the iPhone i use portrait mode.
2. on the iPad i use landscape mode.
3. I use Constraints / Auto layout.
4. Some of the views have nibs, some in code.
5. because of that, the logic is a bit different in each one.
6. iPad have 2 menus you can swipe from top to bottom and left to right.
7. iPhone has no draggable menus.
8. both use same Api calls to the server.

I looked a bit on stack overflow, and got some of those methods:

Should I use 2 different classes, and 2 nibs?
Or maybe 1 class with tons of if else?
Use different targets?

Is one of those is the best way? Is there any other way?

[different targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195512/same-app-for-iphone-and-ipad-but-not-universal)

[same class with if/else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079866/universal-apps-concept-for-iphone-and-ipad)

IPAD::
[image: ipad]

IPHONE::
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I need to design a universal app I look at the interface I think I need to support and try:

1. Can the different layouts be handled by autolayout constraints? If so great, I only need one view.
2. If the views are significantly different can I define a common IBOutlet/Action interface to a view controller? If so I can use one view controller (which is not full of conditional branches) to support views defined in multiple nibs.
3. If the view structure is radically different or the presented view controllers vary greatly (split view controllers for example) then I probably need multiple view controllers, each with their own views/nibs but those controllers should be as thin as possible and share a common set of models, data sources, networking services, and other business logic.

Comment: Any latest approaches today for the above mentioned points considering SwiftUI?